# Kingfisher library not working with pod install

Tags: ios, swift

I had a problem with [HanekeSwift crashes in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735347/uipageviewcontroller-memory-crashes-with-hanekeswift) so I am trying to switch to a different library. 
I am trying Kingfisher and I installed it with cocoapods.

I first tried the 2.6.0 version for a swift 2.3 
and than i have tried the 3.1.1 version for swift 3.0

they both give me the same error:

```
Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'kf_setImageWithUrl' //swift 2.3
Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'kf' //swift 3.0 since code is a little bit different
```

here is my code:

```
import UIKit


class GreenViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageVIew: UIImageView!

  //  var imageUrl: String!

    var pageIndex: Int?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let index = pageIndex {
            if let url = NSURL(string: TutorialPageViewController.urls[index]){
                imageVIew.kf_setImageWithURL(url) //swift 2.3
                imageVIew.kf.setImage(with: url) //swift 3.0
            }
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        //print("pageIndex \(pageIndex)")

           }
}
```

Here is my podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target :'SwipeSingleView’ do
     pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 2.6’ //swift 2.3
     pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 3.0’ //swift 3.0

end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding `import Kingfisher` under `import UIKit` in your `GreenViewController.swift`

Comment: @Cheng-YuHsu Thanks for the idea. I hava tried this before and I simply get `no such module Kingfisher` Even though my Pods folder does include Kingfisher folder.

Comment: Did you open the xcworkspace instead of the xcproject file?

Comment: yes I did. my HanekeSwift library works when i reinstall the pods

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
imageVIew.kf_setImage(with: url)
```

I'm running kingfisher for swift 3 and for some reason that worked despite the docs saying to use `imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)`

Also make sure you have kingfisher imported:

```
import Kingfisher
```

Comment: well it must be something more serious since import Kingfisher already trows an error (no module found even though kingfisher is in my pods folder). I tried reinstalling cocoapods from scratch and than running pod install but it didnt fix the problem.

Comment: @Xitcod13 Only difference between my pod file and yours that I'm seeing is that I'm targeting ios 9 for the project I'm using it in.  That's strange.  Sorry I couldn't have been of more help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for **Kingfisher library** for **download a image**.
and i have one imageview **UserProfileimage** and i have one url thats **URL** name **facebookProfileUrl** and just set image in **UserProfileimage**

You must Have **ImageView+Kingfisher.swift** file in library..

```
 let facebookProfileUrl = self.UserData.valueForKey("picture")!.valueForKey("data")!.valueForKey("url")
        let fbUrl = NSURL(string: facebookProfileUrl as! String)!

        self.UserProfileimage.kf_setImageWithURL(fbUrl, placeholderImage: nil,
                                           optionsInfo: [.Transition(ImageTransition.Fade(1))],
                                           progressBlock: { receivedSize, totalSize in

            },
                                           completionHandler: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
                                            print("Finished")

        })
```

If any Query about this library then put comment i will short out as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following items and the issue was fixed for me:

- Under both project and target, I put the deployment target as version 9.0 (same as defined in the Podfile)
- Under Pods project and target, I set Build Active Architectures Only to NO for both debug and release

Surprisingly, it fixed the issue of not finding the module 'kf'!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have made bad reference, for example

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIView!
```

instead of

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```